# Nesting custom views

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that, on a high level, takes whatever drawable one might pass into it and draws a ring around it, the ring is animated, and comes with a whole set of parameters; things such as ringWidth, gradient colors, etc.

Currently, to show/specify this view in my XML, my markup looks a lot like this:

```
    <RingedImageView
        android:id="@+id/ringedImageView"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gigantic"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_gigantic"
        app:source="@drawable/ic_icon_1"
        app:ringWidth="2dp" />
```

This is all well and good. However, instead of passing in a drawable as the image in the middle, what I would like is to be able to pass in a whole view, entirely seperate from `@id/ringedImageView`.

Ideally, I'd like this to look as follows in my XML:

```
    <RingedImageView
        android:id="@+id/ringedImageView"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gigantic"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_gigantic" ...>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView" .../>

    </RingedImageView>
```

My question then is, can I access that nested ImageView in my RingedImageView.java class? How can I specify how to handle this situation?

Some answers point to having to extend ViewGroup instead of View, but as this isn't a layout manager per se, and the component comes with its own rules for displaying content, a View seems more appropriate. Would appreciate a pointer.

Thanks all

Comment: yes, you need some kind of `ViewGroup` - for example it can be custom `FrameLayout` in its simplest form